# What is the smallest cardinality of a self-linked set in a finite cyclic group?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics, finite-geometry

A subset $A$ of a group $G$ is defined to be *self-linked* if $A\cap gA\ne\emptyset$ for all $g\in G$. This happens if and only if $AA^{-1}=G$.

For a finite group $G$ denote by $sl(G)$ the smallest cardinality of a self-linked set in $G$. It is clear that $sl(G)\ge \sqrt{|G|}$. A more accurate lower bound is $sl(G)\ge \frac{1+\sqrt{4|G|-3}}2$. By a classical result of [Singer (1938)](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1938-043-03/S0002-9947-1938-1501951-4/S0002-9947-1938-1501951-4.pdf), for any power $q=p^k$  of a prime number $p$, the cyclic group $C_n$ of cardinality $n=1+q+q^2$ contains a self-linked subset of cardinality $1+q$, which implies that $sl(C_n)=1+q=\frac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}2$. So, for such numbers $n$ the lower bound $\frac{1+\sqrt{4n-3}}2$ is exact.
In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02631) we prove the upper bound $sl(C_n)\le \sqrt{2n}$ holding for all $n\ne 4$.

**Problem 1.** Is $sl(C_n)=(1+o(1))\sqrt{n}$?

This problem is equivalent to

**Problem 2.** Does the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}{sl(C_n)}/{\sqrt{n}}$ exist?

If the answer to Problems 1,2 are negative, then we can also ask

**Problem 3.** Evaluate the constant $\lambda:=\limsup_{n\to\infty}{sl(C_n)}/{\sqrt{n}}$.

At the moment it is known that $1\le\lambda\le\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Is there a command in GAP to get sl(G) for a group G?

Comment: The sequence of the $sl(C_n)$ starts with $1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,...$. It is not on OEIS.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Good idea, I mean to add this sequence to OEIS. Thanks.

Comment: I vaguely recall that Arieh Lev may have had some results on this problem. Maybe, this paper [http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=321386&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=32&mx-pid=1307974] would be a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Seva, thank you. Unfortunately, I have no access to MR at the moment. Could you write which paper of Arieh Lev you have in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Seva, I have already found the papers of Arieh Lev on ResearchGate. This is exactly was I looked for. Thank you.

Comment: (1) Please, use @Seva next time (not just Seva), otherwise I do not get any notification from the system. (2) If you manage to find in the literature any improvements of the basic bounds $(1+o(1))\sqrt n\le {\rm sl}\,(G)\le(1+o(1))\sqrt{2n}$, please, let me know. (3) Check the recent paper by Kohonen (J. Number Theory, 174 (2017)) and the paper of Mrose it refers to: they manage to improve the trivial upper bound for the parallel sum problem $2A=G$, and it is quite possible that their construction can be modified to work for differences.

Comment: @Seva, I have a very small improvement of the upper bound from $sl(C_n)\le(1+o(1))\sqrt{2n}$ to $sl(C_n)\le \sqrt{2n}$ for all $n\ne 4$ and to $sl(C_n)<\sqrt{2n}$ for all $n$ such that $\sqrt{n/8}\notin\mathbb N$. The proof is written in the updated version of (https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02631) which will appear on arXiv in a couple of days.

Comment: @Seva, I looked at the paper of Kohonen, it resembles me the struggle for a better ruler, see (http://oeis.org/wiki/User:Peter_Luschny/PerfectRulers). By the way the upper bound $sl(C_n)\le\sqrt{2n}$ was proved with the help of the Wichmann ruler.

Answer (score 10):

The difference cover problem has been better studied in the context of $\mathbf{Z}$. Redei, Renyi, and others in the 40s asked for the size of the smallest set $A$ such that $A-A$ covers $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$. They proved an upper bound of roughly $\sqrt{8/3} \sqrt{N}$. To prove this they combined Singer's construction of a perfect difference set with the "perfect ruler" $\{0,1,4,6\}$ (which has difference set $\{-6,\dots,6\}$ each with multiplicity one). This was later improved by Leech and Golay to $\sqrt{8/3 - \epsilon}\sqrt{N}$ (for explicit but not very large $\epsilon$). More interestingly, Redei and Renyi proved a nontrivial lower bound of the form $\sqrt{2 + \frac{4}{3\pi}}\sqrt{N}$.

The upper bound can easily be ported to the cyclic problem by taking $N\approx n/2$ and reducing the set $A$ modulo $n$. This proves an upper bound of roughly $\sqrt{4/3}\sqrt{n}$. However, because of the nontrivial lower bound, this proof technique cannot prove $(1+o(1))\sqrt{n}$. Indeed I think it suggests caution.

Comment: could you give the coordinates of the paper(s) of Leech and Golay with the upper bound $\sqrt{8/3-e}? Thank you.

Comment: Leech: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/s1-31.2.160/full Golay: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/s2-4.4.729/full

Comment: Thank you for the links to the papers of Leech and Golay.